# Symmetry of Quadratic Covariation

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

So with the definition of quadratic covariation between two processes given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_variation), in the case when $Y$ is a Weiner process, is it true that

$$\lim_{||P|| \to 0} \sum_{i=1}^n (X_{(t_k + t_{k-1})/2} - X_{t_{k-1}}) (Y_{t_k} - Y_{t_{k-1}}) = \frac{1}{2} [X,Y]_t$$
when $[X,Y]_t$ exists?

I've tried breaking $[X,Y]_t$ down into
$$\sum_{i=1}^n (X_{(t_k + t_{k-1})/2} - X_{t_{k-1}}) (Y_{t_k} - Y_{t_{k-1}}) + \sum_{i=1}^n (X_{t_k} - X_{(t_k + t_{k-1})/2} ) (Y_{t_k} - Y_{t_{k-1}}) $$
so it reduces down to proving the limits of these two sums are equal. At least from my intuition, since $(-Y_t)$ is a Weiner process, the seccond sum is essentially going backwards from $t$ to 0 with $t_k$ being the left point but I don't know how to justify this properly or if this is even true at all.

Comment: You should break up the difference of $Y$ not that of $X\,.$ And ***most*** importantly: the process is named after Norbert W$\color{red}{\mathbf{ie}}$ner.